# "Low on space" message on an android tablet

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I just got a Agptek 9" tablet.  It's running android 4.04, ICS with 8GB storage and 512MB of RAM.  It generally runs great.  After a few days the tablet is getting a "*low on space*" error message in the notification bar.

In the storage area of settings, it shows over 800MB not used.  Because of this error, it will not allow downloads, including updates and the tablet very runs slow. All downloaded apps have been moved to the SD card.  All cache has been removed.

The only software in the internal storage is android files and apps that came with the tablet, which can not be moved or removed.  Yet, the notification bar shows "*low on space*".  I did a "*factory data reset*" and the problem was resolved for a while.  But, the problem shorty returns.

Can you give me assistance in how to fix this.  Or steer me in the right direction for help.

Comment: Hint: follow the `internal-storage` tag I just added. This is a frequent question, so there are already plenty answers available on our site.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you move apps to the SDcard, the apps will still use space in /data/data/ this is where the user data is stored for the application. this includes things like the database, additional application specific files, other cached data.

Devices that do not have large a /data/data partition are very troublesome with a lot of current applications. Applications like Google+, Chrome, Gmail (just as a couple examples) can use a lot of space in /data/data/.

To see if the issue is /data/data/ you can try and clear Data for some applications and see if the notification goes away. Not just the cache for the application, actually clearing the data.

Comment: Ok, in the storage section of settings, it shows

Answer (score 0):

Seems you RAM usage is on higher side. Install XDA Assistant from Play Store and do some cleanup of your tablet. Its an all in one and comes handy with lots of utility. It has:

1. Document explorer
2. If rooted, you can remove bloatwares.
3. RAM Booster
4. Wifi Explorer
5. App2SD
6. Remove Programs from startup
   and lot more utilities in a single app.

It works well when you have root permissions on your device.Also I would recommend History Eraser to clean any sort of cache.

** Please note , I am just a user of this app not the representative of its company.**

Comment: Ok, in the storage section of settings, it shows: Total space-.98GB,  Apps-148MB. And Available-6.07MB. There is over 800MB unaccounted for.  In the apps section on the "internal storage" scale on the bottom it shows .97GB used with 17MB free.  I'm an old windows man. and It just does add up.

Comment: Oh yes.  When I moved the apps to the sd card, the available space go up to around 250mb and the low space warning went away.  But then, as I was looking at the srorage area, the available space started to chane, all by itself.  I did NOT touch the tablet.  It got lower and lower until the low space warning reappeared.  How is that for Weird?!

Comment: Ok,I just uninstalled all apps except for Adobe Flash Player and Google Play Music, about 20mb total.  Now, storage shows Total Space-.98GB, Apps-121mb, available-29.22mb. Under apps, the "internal storage" bar shows .96gb used with 29mb free. What do I do now?  Do I need to do another Factory Data Reset?

Comment: Oh yes,  after uninstalling all the apps, I still have "insufficient space available to install XDA Assistant.  Thank you,sincerely, for your time and assistance